# Is there a callback function that is triggered on transferFrom?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

- I have a `contract A` that has 5 wETH.
- I have approved `contract B` to spend 1 wETH from `contract A`
- `Contract B` calls `wETH.transferFrom(Contract A, address(this), 1wETH);`

Is there a way to intercept this `transferFrom()` call in `contract A`? Something like a fallback function that would be triggered in A when and if B sent funds to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contract A` can NOT intercept the transaction, because `contract A` is never called during the token transfer.

The information about the balances and approvals of tokens is stored in the `wETH` contract storage, and the actual `transfer()` function (and the state changes that result from this transaction) is also executed only in the context of `wETH` contract.

So, the token transfer is only a call from `contract B` to `wETH`. And `wETH` then produces state changes reflecting:

- decremented token balance of `contract A` address
- incremented token balance of recepient address
- decremented amount of how many `contract A`'s tokens is `contract B` approved to spend

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why is that then we can intercept the regular transfer() call with fallback function?. Shouldn't that also just talk to wETH contract only? I am new to solidity and might be missing some basic knowledge here, so I would appreciate the response. Does that fallback call only work with ETH and not ERC20 tokens?

Comment: The regular `<address>.transfer()` Solidity function creates an Ethereum transaction with ETH value. But when you transfer tokens, you actually create an Ethereum transaction with (usually) empty value that is addressed to the contract address and its **data** field contains instructions for transfer of the tokens. That is in pseudocode `<contract>.call("transfer()")`... I understand it can be a bit confusing. Try going through few lessons in the [CryptoZombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) tutorial, I think they have this concept (difference between regular and token transfer) nicely covered.